# FindMeetingTimes not returning times outside of working hours with "unrestricted" TimeConstraint.ActivityDomain value

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When specifying "Unrestricted" for the TimeConstraint ActivityDomain value, the results only show times during work hours. I'm trying to get available times from 6am-8pm MST and only returns times from 8am-6:30 MST (I haven't seen any returned times later than this.) Adjusting the start/end times has no effect.

The account I'm testing has work hours defined from 6am-8pm MST. I'm running the availability on 20+ users and they all show the same start/end times even though the 'ActivityDomain' is 'Unrestricted'. Thanks in advance!

**Request:** `{
    "MaxCandidates":100,
    "Attendees":[],
    "LocationConstraint":{
        "IsRequired":"false",
        "SuggestLocation":"false"
    },
    "TimeConstraint":{
        "ActivityDomain":"Unrestricted",
        "Timeslots":[{
                "Start":{
                        "DateTime":"2018-08-21T06:00:00.0000000",
                        "TimeZone":"Mountain Standard Time"},
                "End":{
                        "DateTime":"2018-09-01T20:00:00.0000000",
                        "TimeZone":"Mountain Standard Time"}
                }]
    },
    "MeetingDuration":"PT1H",
    "ReturnSuggestionReasons":"true"}`

**PHP result (showing first two days only):**

```
[availableMeetingTimes] => Array
(
    [2018-08-21] => Array
    (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 8
                    [endHour] => 9
                    [start] => 2018-08-21T08:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-21T09:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Tue. 08/21/2018
                    [displayText] => 8:00 AM - 9:00 AM
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 9
                    [endHour] => 10
                    [start] => 2018-08-21T09:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-21T10:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Tue. 08/21/2018
                    [displayText] => 9:00 AM - 10:00 AM
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 10
                    [endHour] => 11
                    [start] => 2018-08-21T10:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-21T11:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Tue. 08/21/2018
                    [displayText] => 10:00 AM - 11:00 AM
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 11
                    [endHour] => 12
                    [start] => 2018-08-21T11:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-21T12:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Tue. 08/21/2018
                    [displayText] => 11:00 AM - 12:00 PM
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 12
                    [endHour] => 13
                    [start] => 2018-08-21T12:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-21T13:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Tue. 08/21/2018
                    [displayText] => 12:00 PM - 1:00 PM
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 14
                    [endHour] => 15
                    [start] => 2018-08-21T14:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-21T15:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Tue. 08/21/2018
                    [displayText] => 2:00 PM - 3:00 PM
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 15
                    [endHour] => 16
                    [start] => 2018-08-21T15:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-21T16:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Tue. 08/21/2018
                    [displayText] => 3:00 PM - 4:00 PM
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 16
                    [endHour] => 17
                    [start] => 2018-08-21T16:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-21T17:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Tue. 08/21/2018
                    [displayText] => 4:00 PM - 5:00 PM
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 17
                    [endHour] => 18
                    [start] => 2018-08-21T17:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-21T18:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Tue. 08/21/2018
                    [displayText] => 5:00 PM - 6:00 PM
                )

        )

    [2018-08-22] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 8
                    [endHour] => 9
                    [start] => 2018-08-22T08:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-22T09:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Wed. 08/22/2018
                    [displayText] => 8:00 AM - 9:00 AM
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 9
                    [endHour] => 10
                    [start] => 2018-08-22T09:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-22T10:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Wed. 08/22/2018
                    [displayText] => 9:00 AM - 10:00 AM
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 10
                    [endHour] => 11
                    [start] => 2018-08-22T10:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-22T11:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Wed. 08/22/2018
                    [displayText] => 10:00 AM - 11:00 AM
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 11
                    [endHour] => 12
                    [start] => 2018-08-22T11:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-22T12:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Wed. 08/22/2018
                    [displayText] => 11:00 AM - 12:00 PM
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 12
                    [endHour] => 13
                    [start] => 2018-08-22T12:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-22T13:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Wed. 08/22/2018
                    [displayText] => 12:00 PM - 1:00 PM
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 13
                    [endHour] => 14
                    [start] => 2018-08-22T13:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-22T14:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Wed. 08/22/2018
                    [displayText] => 1:00 PM - 2:00 PM
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 14
                    [endHour] => 15
                    [start] => 2018-08-22T14:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-22T15:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Wed. 08/22/2018
                    [displayText] => 2:00 PM - 3:00 PM
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 15
                    [endHour] => 16
                    [start] => 2018-08-22T15:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-22T16:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Wed. 08/22/2018
                    [displayText] => 3:00 PM - 4:00 PM
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 16
                    [endHour] => 17
                    [start] => 2018-08-22T16:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-22T17:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Wed. 08/22/2018
                    [displayText] => 4:00 PM - 5:00 PM
                )

            [9] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [startHour] => 17
                    [endHour] => 18
                    [start] => 2018-08-22T17:00:00.0000000
                    [end] => 2018-08-22T18:00:00.0000000
                    [date] => Wed. 08/22/2018
                    [displayText] => 5:00 PM - 6:00 PM
                )
        )
```

Related to resolved: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/580